# Rails best practices of using layouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, actionmailer, partials

I have two classes that derive from ActionMailer. But the deisgn template for both of them are going to be the same. I am going to use layouts. What I have done now is

In Reminder class

```
Class Reminders < ActionMailer::Base
  layouts :mailer_template
end
```

In Alert class

```
Class Alerts < ActionMailer::Base
  layouts :mailer_template
end
```

In layouts I have mailer_template.html

Another way I have is to create two layouts called reminders.html and alerts.html and as they both share the same code I can have a partial called _mailer_template.html and render this partial in bith the classes.

Now which is the best practice to use here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as for me: you don't need create unnecessary files `reminders.html, alerts.html, _shared_partial.html` just use `layouts :layout_name`. Even If in future you will need separate layouts you will be able to do this (but now you don't need it).